# makefile setting a variable in if statement in a target

Tags: makefile, build-process

I have a Makefile with the following:

```
AVAR=""

all : 
    if [ -d ../old ]; then \
    (echo "$@ Ping!"; AVAR="../old"; echo $(AVAR)) \
    fi
    @echo $(AVAR)
```

The idea is that depending on the presence of directory "../old" i will or not
 have information in AVAR (available for use later), however, the if is evaluating to true, and the Ping! is echoed, but nothing is assigned to AVAR, either inside or outside the if statement.

Output is as follows:

```
$ make all
if [ -d ../old ]; then \
        (echo "all Ping!"; AVAR="../old"; echo "") \
        fi
all Ping!
```

Any Insight appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem solved, Did the very bad recursive make option to redefine stuff and reinterpret.

Answer (score 2):

1) Each command in a makefile recipe runs in its own subshell. You define `AVAR` in the first command (the "if" statement), so it's not available to the second command (`@echo $(AVAR)`).

2) Within the first command, you define `AVAR`, but you don't call it right. The term `$(AVAR)` is Make syntax; Make expands it *before* executing the command, and since Make doesn't know anything about such a variable, it expands to nothing. You have to use the shell to expand it, using shell syntax: `$AVAR`. But if you try that, Make will expand the `$A` to nothing, and you'll get "VAR". So you "escape" the `$` with another `$`:

```
all : 
    if [ -d ../old ]; then \
    (echo "$@ Ping!"; AVAR="../old"; echo $$AVAR) \
    fi
```

Comment: Almost, It works for the echo within the if, but not the one outside the if.

Comment: @NWS, As I said in 1), the value you assign in one command is not available in another. Do you want to use the value again in the same rule (`all`), or in a different rule?

Comment: "available for use later" - i assumed this meant within this rule, _and_ when other rules are evaluated later, which is why i declared AVAR _before_ the rule definition(s).

Comment: @NWS, Make doesn't work that way, but there are ways... Is that directory `../old` built or removed by Make? That is, does its existence depend on what rules have already been run?

Comment: Its existance does not depend on any rules that have been run. I will be wanting to add "old" or another known directory to an include path, depending on their presence or not.

Comment: Then why not just add them both? Are you using a tool that objects to nonexistent files in an include path? (In particular, gcc doesn't.)

Comment: In a way... The client will not want to accept the _possibility_ of including other source trees (even if there is no directory there) - so no i cannot put all the directories there.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(echo "$@ Ping!"; AVAR="../old"; echo $$AVAR) \
```

instead of

```
(echo "$@ Ping!"; AVAR="../old"; echo $(AVAR)) \
```

Comment: Almost, It works for the echo _within_ the if, but not the one outside the if.

Comment: Easiest solution? Just chain it on by putting ;\ after `fi`.

Answer (score 0):

That may be a bit late, but in case someone else has the same question.

The way I handle it is by evaluating the if in a shell function and extract the stdout to a variable that's usable in the next command.

Method 1: appending the echo to the AVAR setting

```
    if [ -d ../old ]; then \
    (echo "$@ Ping!") \
    fi

    AVAR=$(shell if [ -d ../old ]; then \
    (AVAR="../old"; echo $${AVAR}) \
    fi;) && \
    echo $${AVAR}
```

or Method 2: evaluating the variable so that it could be used throughout the target without appending the `echo ${AVAR}` to the same shell.

```
    if [ -d ../old ]; then \
    (echo "$@ Ping!") \
    fi

    $(eval AVAR=$(shell if [ -d ../old ]; then \
    (AVAR="../old"; echo $${AVAR}) \
    fi;))
    @echo ${AVAR}
```

instead of

```
    if [ -d ../old ]; then \
    (echo "$@ Ping!"; AVAR="../old"; echo $(AVAR)) \
    fi
    @echo $(AVAR)
```

---

Notes:
- `AVAR` being set by the $(shell ... ) output is a different variable from the one inside the if condition
- If you want to use a single if, you'll have to remove the stdout of "$@ ping" from the beginning of AVAR content