# Setting a variable in an if statement in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I've read this ([makefile setting a variable in if statement in a target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849870/makefile-setting-a-variable-in-if-statement-in-a-target)) but I'm still not getting this to work at all.

How do I get the below to print "fooz"?

My goal is to have an ifeq statement that results in the assigment to the "MISMATCH" variable, that (later in the target) is used in a different if statement.

```
a =
MISMATCH=

all:
ifeq ($(a),)
    MISMATCH=yes
endif

ifdef MISMATCH
$(info fooz)
else
$(info bark)
endif
```

**EDIT**

I would like the file to look like this:

```
VALUE_TO_TEST=bad_value
MISMATCH=

all:
    ifeq ($(VALUE_TO_TEST), expected_value)
        MISMATCH=yes
    endif

    ifdef MISMATCH
        # Do thing because there is a mismatch
    else
        # Do thing where there is no mismatch
    endif
```

Comment: I don't see any part of that question or answer that would lead someone to believe that `$(MISMATCH = yes)` is a valid way to assign a variable...?  That just expands a variable with the highly unusual name `MISMATCH = yes`.

Comment: I can't figure out what you actually want to do here.  Your question "how to get "fooz" printed" can be easily accomplished: just replace `$(MISMATCH = yes)` with `MISMATCH = yes` (making sure that there is no TAB before that assignment) which is a correct assignment of a makefile variable.  But probably you really have other requirements, which you haven't specified here.

Comment: Ok, I tried to add a bit of clarity. It really is this simple: have ifeq statement that results in the assigment to the "MISMATCH" variable, that (later in the target) is used in a different if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot combine make constructs, like `ifeq`, with shell constructs, like setting a shell variable.  Makefiles are not scripts, like a shell script or a python script or whatever.

Make works in two distinct phases: first ALL the makefiles are parsed, all make variables are assigned, all `ifeq` statements are resolved, and all targets and prerequisites are parsed and make constructs an internal graph of all the relationships between them.  Basically, everything that is not indented with a TAB is parsed in this phase.

Second, after ALL makefiles are parsed, make will walk (some part of) the graph created in the first step and, for targets that are out of date, it will expand the recipe (which is a shell script) then run a shell and give it the recipe.  Everything that's indented with a TAB is handled in this phase.

So, clearly you can't have ifeq conditions (expanded during the first phase) that depend on actions in recipes (run in the second phase).

You can write your makefile like this:

```
VALUE_TO_TEST = bad_value
MISMATCH =
ifeq ($(VALUE_TO_TEST), expected_value)
   MISMATCH = yes
endif

all:
ifdef MISMATCH
        # Do thing because there is a mismatch
else
        # Do thing where there is no mismatch
endif
```

I expect you don't want to do this, but although this second example is better than the first it still doesn't really explain enough about what you want to do, and why it's not acceptable to do things this way.

Comment: this is valuable! the purpose here is to use the makefile to detected a mismatch of stated architecture and the ACTUAL architecture (this is for users who have frequently reported making mistakes like downloading our dev environment with the wrong binary specified (e.g. using something from rosetta, when non-rosetta is required; using a go binary for amd64 when arm64 is required; etc). It's all just error checking.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh - so the answer after MANY permutations is the tab mistake:

```
a =
MISMATCH=

all:
ifeq ($(a),)
MISMATCH=yes
endif

ifdef MISMATCH
$(info fooz)
else
$(info bark)
endif
```

(make files are so frustrating)

Comment: The rule is simple: any line that is NOT part of a recipe (not a shell command used to build a target) should not be indented with a TAB.  Any line that IS part of a recipe (a shell command used to build a target) must be indented with a TAB.  You can use spaces to indent makefile statements if you want, but not TAB.  Also if you have a new-enough version of GNU make, you can use the `.RECIPEPREFIX` variable to change the recipe intro from TAB to some other character.

Comment: Another way to solve your problem here, would be to move the `all:` target to appear at the end after all the variables have been set, rather than in the middle of the makefile.

Comment: Oh, to be clear, the items below are supposed to be IN the target. How do I do that?

Comment: Sorry but that wasn't clear to me, at least :).  What are "the items below", and what does "IN the target" mean?  It would be helpful if you could edit your question and provide an example of what you want to do, that accurately reflects what you actually do want to do, rather than using things like `$(info fooz)` etc. where it's completely unclear what the requirements are.

Comment: The thing i don't understand about .RECIPEPREFIX is the ifeq is part of the recipe, but shouldn't be indented with tab?

Comment: Ok! I updated the question to give you my desired state for the code

Comment: The `ifeq` is *not* part of the recipe, even if the text within is.  The `ifeq` is to be processed by `make`, when it parses the makefile, not to be passed to a shell for execution when target `all` is built.

Comment: Additionally, your remarks make me think that you are trying to define a variable that is scoped to a particular target or recipe.  Although GNU `make` does provide target-specific variables as an extension, they are rarely used, and even more rarely necessary.  Makefiles are specifications, not scripts, and you will not be at harmony with `make` until you truly understand that.

Comment: oh wow, i truly did not understand that. fascinating (and helpful). 

So what's best practice for moderately complicated things that require shell like functionality? just create a script and execute it?